# What does the number of the default Nest.js system logs represent?

Tags: logging, nestjs

Nest.js default system logs produce logs like the below. What's the meaning of the number
76096 after `[Nest]`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the process id or `pid`. You can use it in Unix commands like `KILL` to end a hung process via the command line.